# Fastest way to iterate over dict of dicts and change only 1 element of the encapsulated dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Say you have a dict `my_dict` where all its elements are dictionaries.

What is the fastest way to iterate over all elements and change only 1 element of the encapsulated dict ?

basically this but faster:

```
for sub_dict in my_dict:
    sub_dict["key_2"] = sub_dict["key_2"][0]
```

Note: I would be interested if anyone points out a way to do this with lambda functions

Comment: `my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}` is what you want?

Comment: Although I am not sure if this is faster

Comment: I don't think there will be anything faster than a `for` loop with this data structure. With dict comprehension it will become as complex as `{key: dict(sub_dict, **{"key": sub_dict["key"][0]}) for key, sub_dict in my_dict.items()}`. If anything, have you through about parallelising it? Also, I'm not sure there are any nice lambda solutions either, maybe something with `map`? But ultimately, if you need something *really fast* probably add parallelism or use a different language.

Answer (score 0):

So, I rewrote your example (as it not kinda working) and compared with my dict comprehension

```
import datetime

my_dict = {i: [i ** 2] for i in range(1000000)}

now = datetime.datetime.now()
for sub_dict in my_dict:
    my_dict[sub_dict] = my_dict[sub_dict][0]

print("First", datetime.datetime.now() - now)  # First 0:00:00.088934
my_dict = {i: [i ** 2] for i in range(100000)}

now = datetime.datetime.now()
my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}  # Second 0:00:00.007972
print("Second", datetime.datetime.now() - now)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but no in fact I want to return the sub_dicts with only one key changed

Answer (score 0):

This works, should be faster than the for loop. Not sure if it's optimal

```
[dict(sub_dict,key_2=sub_dict["key_2"][0])(sub_dict) for sub_dict in my_dict]
```